# .TargetPath was unexpected at this time

Tags: windows-7, command-line, powershell

I want to obtain the Target of all the shortcut situated in taskbar folder. I am running following code in .bat file

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%i IN ("C:\Users\kirti\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\*.lnk") DO (
powershell $sh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
powershell $target = $sh.CreateShortcut('%%i').TargetPath
powershell echo $target
)
```

and it is giving me error saying .TargetPath is unexpected at this time.

Comment: PowerShell variables does not survive process termination.

Comment: @PetSerAl Please Explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking powershell 3 times, they don't share the same scope.

- Append the commands in one line separated by a semicolon to have one scope.
- Use the environment variable `APPDATA` to address the folder for the current user.

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\10\02\SU_1363191.cmd
@ECHO OFF
FOR %%i IN ("%AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\*.lnk") DO (
  powershell -Nop -c "$sh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell;\".lnk: {0}`nPath: {1}`n\" -f '%%~nxi',$sh.CreateShortcut('%%i').TargetPath"
)
```

The above batch is quite slow as it invokes powershell separatly for each iteration of `%%i`, this powershell script iterates the .lnk files itself.

```
## Q:\Test\2018\10\02\SU_1363191.ps1
$sh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
Get-ChildItem "$($Env:AppData)\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\*.lnk"|
%{".lnk: {0}`nPath: {1}`n" -f $_.Name,$sh.CreateShortcut($_.FullName).TargetPath}
```

and can also be wrapped in a batch:

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\10\02\SU_1363191_2.cmd
@powershell -Nop -c "$sh = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell;gci \""$($Env:AppData)\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar\*.lnk\""|ForEach{\"".lnk: {0}`nPath: {1}`n\"" -f $_.Name,$sh.CreateShortcut($_.FullName).TargetPath}"
```

Same sample output for all 3 variants:

```
> SU_1363191.cmd
.lnk: Bash on Ubuntu on Windows.lnk
Path: C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe

.lnk: Command Prompt.lnk
Path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe

.lnk: Mozilla Firefox.lnk
Path: C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe

.lnk: PowerShell 6 (x64).lnk
Path: C:\Program Files\PowerShell\6\pwsh.exe

.lnk: Visual Studio Code.lnk
Path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe
```

Comment: I don't quite understand. Is this creating shortcuts (`$sh.CreateShortcut(...)`) or doing something else?